# unable to compile apache drill code

Tags: apache-drill

I cloned the drill git repository and when I run

`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

I get this error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (validate_java_and_maven_version) on project drill-root: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JDK 1.7 to build Apache Drill.

The Drill team added [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to the build process to make sure that build gives an error if someone tries to build using an unsupported version of Java or Maven. If you scroll up you will see an earlier error message like the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (validate_java_and_maven_version) @ drill-root ---
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-51 is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8).
```

A lot of people want to run Drill using JDK 1.8. There's good news on that front. While you can't *build* using JDK 1.8, once you've built, you can *run* Drill with JDK 1.8 just fine.